# Is there a way to make a lot of RestTemplate calls to a paginated endpoint automatically to fetch all the pages

Tags: java, spring, pagination, resttemplate

Suppose we have a paginated API which returns some data and also page/perPage/pages/totalCount values. We need to retrieve all the pages in a loop on a client side using Spring `RestTemplate`.

A simple way would be making one single call with `page=1`, then getting `pages` value (or calculate it if it's not exist in a way like `totalCount/perPage`), and finally, performing several calls with `page=2..pages`.

Is there a way to do it automatically? I can imagine, e.g., passing `Pageable` somehow to the one of `RestTemplate` overloaded methods but it seems there is no appropriate method for that. Maybe some other solutions exist? I'm open to using any of 3rd party libraries if needed.